# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'classname' not found in path/to/folder/or/file

Tags: php, fatal-error, ubuntu-16.04, file-not-found

I am trying to run a PHP program through terminal in ubuntu16.04

while running the code I go following error:-

```
vyclean06@vyclean06-desktop:/var/www/html$ php php_sele.php
PHP Warning:  include(/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPWebDriver_WebDriver' not found in /var/www/html/php_sele.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 6
```

Here is my PHP file :-

```
<?php
// include dirname(__FILE__)."/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php";
include "/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php";
$wd_host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$web_driver = new PHPWebDriver_WebDriver($wd_host);
$session = $web_driver->session('firefox');
?>
```

Code is in same directory where the library folder is kept i.e. in `/var/www/html/`

Suppose I used `dirname(__FILE__)` same error thrown

```
vyclean06@vyclean06-desktop:/var/www/html$ php php_sele.php
PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPWebDriver_WebDriver' not found in /var/www/html/php_sele.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 6
```

I am using PHP 7.0...

What should be done by me to encounter the error...?

Thank You in Advance :)

Comment: Try removing the leading `/` as that says go back to the root directory and then start looking up the directory structure from there

Comment: Getting same error @RiggsFolly , I am not getting `PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/php_sele.php on line 2` what exactly it means

Comment: Does that file exist in that directory? Does the account that the webserver is running under have persissions to access it

Comment: What directory is the script in?

Comment: my code contains at `/var/www/html/` and library where file `WebDriver.php` is kept at `/var/www/html/php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/WebDriver.php`. `WebDriver.php` containing class PHPWebDriver_WebDriver

Comment: Then `include "php-webdriver/PHPWebDriver/webdriver.php";` should work